# Unclear instructions witht lastest guide Sponsor UserOperations with Pimlico

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

I'd like to give my feedback regarding your latest guide, it isn't quite plug-and-play and I had to do a couple of modifications and digging to find out what was wrong.

I refer to the following guide : https://docs.safe.global/home/4337-guides/pimlico-sponsor-account

First, there are several lines where a parameter isn't needed and creates errors, since the guide initializes the bundlerClient like so

```
  transport: http(PIMLICO_API_V1),
  chain: gnosis
})
  .extend(bundlerActions(ENTRYPOINT_ADDRESS_V06))
  .extend(pimlicoBundlerActions(ENTRYPOINT_ADDRESS_V06))
```

Steps 7 and 9 are triggering errors because of the field entrypoint which is already initialized above:
[image]

```
  const sponsorResult = await pimlicoPaymasterClient.sponsorUserOperation({
    userOperation: sponsoredUserOperation,
    entryPoint: ENTRYPOINT_ADDRESS_V06,
    sponsorshipPolicyId: SPONSORSHIP_POLICY_ID
  })
```

```
const userOperationHash = await bundlerClient.sendUserOperation({
  userOperation: sponsoredUserOperation,
  entryPoint: ENTRYPOINT_ADDRESS_V06
})
```

Second, during the step init code in the file 'getInitializerCode.ts' the function generateApproveCallData is missing. This is the code I used for the function:

```
const generateApproveCallData = (paymasterAddress: Hash) => {
  return encodeFunctionData({
    abi: erc20Abi,
    functionName: "approve",
    args: [
      paymasterAddress,
      0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffn,
    ],
  });
};
```

Finally, I had an issue with the gas estimation (step 7) where I was getting the following error:

```
Possible solutions:
• Verify that the verificationGasLimit is high enough to cover the validateUserOp function's gas costs.
• Make sure validateUserOp returns uint(1) for invalid signatures, and MUST NOT REVERT when the signature is invalid
• If you are not using a paymaster, verify that the sender address has enough native tokens to cover the required pre-fund. Consider leveraging functions like getRequiredPrefund.
• Verify that the validateUserOp function is implemented with the correct logic, and that the user operation is supposed to be valid.

Docs: https://docs.pimlico.io/bundler/reference/entrypoint-errors/aa23
```

After a while, I fixed it by moving step 8 (Signature) before the gas estimation `estimateUserOperationGas` and I did another signature after the estimation, which seems weird to me but at least it works now.

EDIT: It seems you can use a dummy signature like so "0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0000000000000000000000000000000007aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1c"  before the gas estimation as per https://docs.pimlico.io/bundler/reference/endpoints/eth_estimateUserOperationGas.

Please, let me know if I misunderstood something and thank you for the new content.